# Place checkbox inline with label

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap documentation and SO answers don't seem to be answering this one for me. I want to put a checkbox next to its label. It's simple. I must be doing something wrong, but cannot figure it out.

I'm using:

```
#gemfile.lock, in my Rails application.

bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)
rails (4.0.3)
```

In my Rails view:

```
# devise/registrations/new.html.erb
  <%= f.label :accept_terms, class: "checkbox" do %>
    <%= f.check_box :accept_terms %> I agree to the terms and conditions listed here
  <% end %>
```

Which generates the following HTML:

```
  <label class="checkbox" for="user_accept_terms">
    <input name="user[accept_terms]" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="user_accept_terms" name="user[accept_terms]" type="checkbox" value="1"> I agree to the terms and conditions listed here
  </label>
```

Alternately, in the view:

```
# devise/registrations/new.html.erb
  <%= f.label :accept_terms, "I agree to the terms and conditions listed here", class: "checkbox" %>
  <%= f.check_box :accept_terms %>
```

Which yields the HTML:

```
  <label class="checkbox" for="user_accept_terms">I agree to the terms and conditions listed here</label>
  <input name="user[accept_terms]" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="user_accept_terms" name="user[accept_terms]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Both attempts result in the checkbox and label appearing on separate lines.

I have even tried manually overriding the block display attributes (successfully, according to Chome's Inspect):

```
#user_accept_terms { display: inline;}
label.checkbox { display: inline; }
```

How can I get these elements to behave?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete block `do...end`

```
 <fieldset>
  <%= f.label :accept_terms, class: "checkbox"  %>
   <%= f.check_box :accept_terms %>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: I tried that originally. Same result. I've updated my question to show what that code looks like as well.

Comment: What class in form? looks like bootstrap overwrite you `css`

Comment: No special form class. Just trying to replicate the bootstrap basic example: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: What's happens if you write outside of `fieldset`?

Comment: It looks the same. I've tested it both ways just now, and updated my question for clarity.

Comment: Ok, I stubbed ( , just look my fiddle from scratch http://jsfiddle.net/8tw7v/241/

Comment: Works in the fiddle. What appears to be the same syntax isn't working in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the example below to work?

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how exactly how to get rails to generate that type of code for you, but that seems to be the way the bootstrap docs recommend... [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

Comment: I've tried this, with the div and the checkbox and text inside the label brackets. Rails puts out more details, which I can't suppress, but essentially it looks as you typed.

Comment: It sounds like you must have some other CSS that may be conflicting, I tried that HTML with the standard bootstrap template and it was displaying side by side for me...